# Clicking on link changes route but not Component itself - React Hook Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hookrouter

I'm facing the ReactJS routing issue. [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-currying-snw0g?file=/src/App.js). I'm using the `hookrouter` package.

**Issue:**

As mentioned in the demo, if I'm on the `/users` route and when I click on `about` link, the URL changes but `About` Component is not getting loaded.

**What I want?**

Is there a way to load a Component when I click on its link?

```
import { A, useRoutes } from "hookrouter";

const Users = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <A href="/about">About</A>
    </div>
  );
};

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About</h1>
      <A href="/users">Users</A>
    </div>
  );
};

const routes = {
  "/users": () => <Users />,
  "/about": () => <About />
};

function App() {
  const routeResult = useRoutes(routes);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <A href="/users">Users Page</A>
      </div>
      <div>
        <A href="/about">About Page</A>
      </div>
      {routeResult}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>, rootElement);
```

Comment: Please add some codes here. code sandbox is ok but maybe it will have changes in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Paratron/hookrouter/issues/115) in hookrouter library where if you wrap your app with `<React.StrictMode>` the navigations doesn't work.

So, for now, remove the strict mode and you will be fine.

**index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  // <React.StrictMode> // <------ comment this for now.
  <App />,
  // </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

[working copy of your codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hook-router-issue-fix-eu8my)

Comment: Will there be any issues if I remove StrictMode?